# Make ignores generated dependencies

Tags: build, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to write a Makefile for my project that automatically generates the dependencies between my source files.
The Makefile is as follows:

```
CC = g++

CFLAGS  = -std=c++11 -Wfatal-errors -fdiagnostics-color=always
LDFLAGS = -lm -lfftw3

SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj
DEPDIR = dep

SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJS = $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRCS)) 
DEPS = $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(SRCS))

PROG = whistle_recognition

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o$(PROG) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean run

$(DEPS): $(DEPDIR)/%.d : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $< -MF $@

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -r $(OBJS) $(DEPS) $(PROG) 

run: $(PROG)
    ./$(PROG)

-include $(DEPS)
```

Generating the dependencies works fine. However, Make ignores them.
Suppose I have a file foo.cpp that includes the header file quux.h .
If foo.cpp changes Make rebuilds foo.o. However if quux.h changes Make thinks that foo.o is up to date. How can I fix this?

Edit:
Heres more info: output of `make -d whistle_recognition | grep signalscanner.d`:

```
Reading makefile 'dep/signalscanner.d' (search path) (don't care) (no ~ expansion)...
 Considering target file 'dep/signalscanner.d'.
  File 'dep/signalscanner.d' does not exist.
  Finished prerequisites of target file 'dep/signalscanner.d'.
 Must remake target 'dep/signalscanner.d'.
g++ -std=c++11 -Wfatal-errors -fdiagnostics-color=always -MM src/signalscanner.cpp -MF dep/signalscanner.d
Putting child 0xcda970 (dep/signalscanner.d) PID 2404 on the chain.
Live child 0xcda970 (dep/signalscanner.d) PID 2404 
 Successfully remade target file 'dep/signalscanner.d'.
Reading makefile 'dep/signalscanner.d' (search path) (don't care) (no ~ expansion)...
 Considering target file 'dep/signalscanner.d'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file 'dep/signalscanner.d'.
  Prerequisite 'src/signalscanner.cpp' is older than target 'dep/signalscanner.d'.
 No need to remake target 'dep/signalscanner.d'.
```

output of `make -p whistle_recognition | signalscanner.o`(shortened):

```
[...]
obj/signalscanner.o: src/signalscanner.cpp
[...]
signalscanner.o: src/signalscanner.cpp src/signalscanner.h src/frequencyanalyzer.h src/freqanalyzer_test.h src/wav_file.h src/signalscanner_test.h
```

And theres the problem: `g++` doesn't include the `obj/`-prefix to the targets... Is there a way to fix this via pattern substitution?

Comment: Can you show the `dep/foo.d` file? Do you see make including the `dep/foo.d` file in the `make -d` output? Does the `make -p` output show `quux.h` anywhere? As a dep for `foo.o`?

Comment: Heres the `dep/signalscanner.d` file: `signalscanner.o: src/signalscanner.cpp src/signalscanner.h \
 src/frequencyanalyzer.h src/freqanalyzer_test.h src/wav_file.h \
 src/signalscanner_test.h`

Comment: Well, the dependencies are generated incorrectly. See my solution.

Comment: See `signalscanner.o`? That's not what you are building. That's the problem. You need to fix that. I don't know if you can get `gcc` to automatically spit out the target with a prefix of if you'll have to `sed`/etc. it in to the file but fix that and it'll work.

Comment: The `-MT` argument for `gcc` can do what you want here but Maxim Egorushkin's answer is a better one in general.

Comment: `rm -r` should probably be `rm -f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People often have such rules for dependency generation, but they are really unnecessary.

The first time a project is built no dependencies are necessary since it builds all sources anyway. It is only the subsequent builds that require the dependencies from the previous build to detect what needs to be rebuilt.

The dependencies are just a by-product of compilation.

---

The generated dependencies contain paths to corresponding `.o` files. Since `.o` output paths were not specified when generating dependencies, those paths are incorrect.

The following solution puts `.d` files along with corresponding `.o` files and those `.d` files contain the correct paths to `.o`. It also does compilation and dependencies in one pass.

Fixes:

Remove these lines:

```
$(DEPS): $(DEPDIR)/%.d : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $< -MF $@
-include $(DEPS)
```

Update these lines:

```
DEPS = $(OBJS:%.o=%.d)
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -MD -MP -o $@ $<
```

Add these lines at the bottom:

```
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
-include $(DEPS)
endif
```

Comment: @EtanReisner Added an explanation for you.

Comment: Much better, thanks. Though I'd probably have kept the `DEPS` variable for clarity.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yep, with `DEPS` variable the changes are shorter.

Comment: I had to remove the if-guard at the end but its working now. Thanks!

Comment: @Vector That is a minor optimization to not include dependencies when cleaning.