# Using G++, Undefined Reference std:: Makefile

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, g++

I've been working on getting a server/client running for a simple single-threaded messenger service.  It's able to compile on Visual Studio but when I attempt to compile it on Linux via a makefile, using the command: `make client`, I get a very large list of errors.  I will provide the beginning part and then a list of errors:

Here it says that it is at least trying to use g++:

> g++ -g    -c -o client.o client.cc cc   client.o   -o client client.o:
>   In function `main':
>   /home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:10:
>   undefined reference to`std::allocator::allocator()'
>
> EDIT: I noticed something unusual here.  When I call `make client` again without calling `make clean` I get the following:
>
> peter@peter-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger$ make client
>       cc   client.o   -o client
>       client.o: In function `main':
>       /home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:10: undefined reference to`std::allocator::allocator()'
>   Not sure if this is significant or not, but it doesn't mention g++ again.

Snippet of said errors:

```
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:7: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:7: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:7: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:15: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(char const*)'
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:18: undefined reference to `std::cout'
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:18: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:18: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:18: undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:23: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:23: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:7: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:25: undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:25: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:7: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
client.o: In function `Client::Client(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)':
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:27: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()'
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:27: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()'
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:29: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/home/peter/Desktop/CS360/Messaging_Service/messenger/client.cc:32: undefined reference to `operator new[](unsigned long)'
```

This leads me to believe that there is an error with my makefile.  I use g++ and I believe it also is set to compile just fine as well, so I am not too sure where to go from here.  My Makefile is:

```
CXX=    g++ $(CCFLAGS)

MSG-SERVER= server.o
MSG-CLIENT= client.o
OBJS =      $(MSG-SERVER) $(MSG-CLIENT)

LIBS = 

CCFLAGS = -g

all:    msg-server msg-client

msg-server:$(MSG-SERVER)
    $(CXX) -o server $(MSG-SERVER) $(LIBS)

msg-client:$(MSG-CLIENT)
    $(CXX) -o client $(MSG-CLIENT) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(OBJS:.o=.d)

realclean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(OBJS:.o=.d) server client


# These lines ensure that dependencies are handled automatically.
%.d:    %.cc
    $(SHELL) -ec '$(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< \
        | sed '\''s/\($*\)\.o[ :]*/\1.o $@ : /g'\'' > $@; \
        [ -s $@ ] || rm -f $@'

include $(OBJS:.o=.d)
```

If needed I'll link my code as well: https://bitbucket.org/picklepetters/messenger/src/44e4fa12541948215f874b56e4ba0dedea1766f5/client.cc?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

When I trace make with `make -d` it gives me a HUGE amount of data.  I'll post some snippets of what was given, because I honestly have no idea what I am looking at:

```
 Trying implicit prerequisite '/usr/include/c++/5/SCCS/s.stdexcept.F'.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'stdexcept'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite '/usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept.r'.
      Looking for a rule with intermediate file '/usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept.r'.
       Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
       Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
       Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'stdexcept'.
       Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite '/usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept.l'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'stdexcept.r'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite '/usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept.r,v'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'stdexcept.r'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite '/usr/include/c++/5/RCS/stdexcept.r,v'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'stdexcept.r'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite '/usr/include/c++/5/RCS/stdexcept.r'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'stdexcept.r'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite '/usr/include/c++/5/s.stdexcept.r'.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'stdexcept.r'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite '/usr/include/c++/5/SCCS/s.stdexcept.r'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'stdexcept'.
     Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite '/usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept.F'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem 'stdexcept'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite '/usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept.m'.
     Looking for a rule with intermediate file '/usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept.m'.
      Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
      Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'stdexcept'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite '/usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept.ym'.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'stdexcept.m'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite '/usr/include/c++/5/stdexcept.m,v'.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'stdexcept.m'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite '/usr/include/c++/5/RCS/stdexcept.m,v'.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'stdexcept.m'.
      Trying implicit prerequisite '/usr/include/c++/5/RCS/stdexcept.m'.
      Trying pattern rule with stem 'stdexcept.m'.
```

It's like that until maybe 150~ lines towards the end when it says that it has finished the prerequisites of target file:

```
Finished prerequisites of target file 'server.d'.
  Prerequisite 'server.cc' is older than target 'server.d'.
  Prerequisite 'server.cc' is older than target 'server.d'.
  Prerequisite '/usr/include/stdc-predef.h' is older than target 'server.d'.
  Prerequisite 'server.h' is older than target 'server.d'.
  Prerequisite '/usr/include/errno.h' is older than target 'server.d'.
  Prerequisite '/usr/include/features.h' is older than target 'server.d'.
  Prerequisite '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/cdefs.h' is older than target 'server.d'.
  Prerequisite '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/wordsize.h' is older than target 'server.d'.
  Prerequisite '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs.h' is older than target 'server.d'.
  Prerequisite '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnu/stubs-64.h' is older than target 'server.d'.
  Prerequisite '/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/errno.h' is older than target 'server.d'.
```

for the last 100 lines it states:

```
Must remake target 'server.o'.
g++ -g    -c -o server.o server.cc
Putting child 0x13601a0 (server.o) PID 7768 on the chain.
Live child 0x13601a0 (server.o) PID 7768 
server.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
server.cc:19:17: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
                 cout << "server [-p port]" << endl;
                 ^
server.cc:19:47: error: ‘endl’ was not declared in this scope
                 cout << "server [-p port]" << endl;
                                               ^
server.cc: In constructor ‘Server::Server(int)’:
server.cc:34:30: error: ‘>>’ should be ‘> >’ within a nested template argument list
     map<string, vector<string>> mappedMessages;
                              ^
server.cc: At global scope:
server.cc:121:36: error: ‘String’ has not been declared
 Server::handle_message(int client, String message) {
                                    ^
server.cc:121:1: error: prototype for ‘void Server::handle_message(int, int)’ does not match any in class ‘Server’
 Server::handle_message(int client, String message) {
 ^
In file included from server.cc:1:0:
server.h:33:12: error: candidate is: std::__cxx11::string Server::handle_message(int, std::__cxx11::string)
     string handle_message(int, string);
            ^
server.cc:127:35: error: ‘String’ has not been declared
 Server::parse_message(int client, String message) {
                                   ^
server.cc:127:1: error: prototype for ‘std::__cxx11::string Server::parse_message(int, int)’ does not match any in class ‘Server’
 Server::parse_message(int client, String message) {
 ^
In file included from server.cc:1:0:
server.h:34:12: error: candidate is: std::__cxx11::string Server::parse_message(int, std::__cxx11::string)
     string parse_message(int, string);
            ^
server.cc:190:63: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘store_message’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 Server::store_message(string name, string subject, string data) {
                                                               ^
server.cc:190:1: error: prototype for ‘int Server::store_message(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)’ does not match any in class ‘Server’
 Server::store_message(string name, string subject, string data) {
 ^
In file included from server.cc:1:0:
server.h:36:10: error: candidate is: void Server::store_message(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)
     void store_message(string, string, string);
          ^
server.cc: In member function ‘std::__cxx11::string Server::get_subjects(std::__cxx11::string)’:
server.cc:210:5: error: ‘mappedMessages’ was not declared in this scope
  if(mappedMessages.find(name) != mappedMessages.empty()) {
     ^
server.cc:214:15: error: missing template arguments before ‘it’
  for(iterator it = mappedMessages.at(name).begin(); it != mappedMessages.at(name).end(); ++it)   {
               ^
server.cc:214:53: error: ‘it’ was not declared in this scope
  for(iterator it = mappedMessages.at(name).begin(); it != mappedMessages.at(name).end(); ++it)   {
                                                     ^
server.cc:214:59: error: ‘mappedMessages’ was not declared in this scope
  for(iterator it = mappedMessages.at(name).begin(); it != mappedMessages.at(name).end(); ++it)   {
                                                           ^
server.cc:219:29: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ and ‘int’)
   response = response + " " + counter + " " + mappedMessages.at(name).it.front() + "\n";
```

Comment: can you show us the full trace of your makefile execution? I suspect that there is some C compiling involved...

Comment: Ok, I just put it into the original post, if that was what you meant by the full trace, I entered in file path to the makefile execution

Comment: I mean: the trace of the `make` execution, and in the question, please.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I just updated it again.

Comment: Based on error messages like `error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope` it looks to me like you didn't `#include <iostream>` (or equivalent header) in your source file, or else you haven't set the `std` namespace.

Comment: compiles fine here (I'm on windows, I had to adapt a little bit) using g++ v4. Looks like the compiler does not see the `using namespace std` that you put in the .h file. Try to put it in the .cc file again. But that's strange.

Comment: I have `#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;` in my header file.  Would there be any reason for the makefile to not include my header with this?

Comment: I added both `using namespace std;` and `#include <iostream>`  to the .cc file just in case, and I still have the same issue

Comment: What version of gcc are you using? Run `g++ -v`.

Comment: gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.2)

Comment: It should not be using `std::__cxx11::string` when not in C++11 mode -- you have some sort of problem with the compiler installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is using

```
make client
```

instead of

```
make msg-client
```

Since there is no target for client, make defaults to using cc. This is shown in the first yellow box in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Those `undefined reference to 'std::allocator<char>::allocator()'` errors normally mean that `libstdc++` is not linked in, most often because people link with `gcc` instead of `g++`.

The dependency generation rule uses `$(CC)` instead of `$(CXX)`, this is what causes those compiler errors. In fact, this rule has been unnecessary for a decade now. What you should do is the following:

1. Remove that `%.d` rule and its recipe entirely.
2. Direct the compiler to produce the dependencies (`-MD -MP`) when compiling `.cc` to `.o` (your makefile uses [the built-in rule `%.o` : `%.cc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules)):

   ```
   %.o : %.cc
       $(CXX) -c -o $@ -MD -MP ${CPPFLAGS} ${CXXFLAGS} $<
   ```
3. Change `include $(OBJS:.o=.d)` to `-include $(OBJS:.o=.d)`.

Nothing else is required to generate and use dependencies. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32379965/412080 for more details.

Comment: I understand that, and if you look at the Makefile, it uses g++ and not gcc.  Is  it not getting the g++ part and just defaulting to gcc?

Comment: @Petorix Updated the answer.

Comment: Turns out I was making the mistake of confusing this makefile with another I was coding.  As a result I was typing a different make command, so it found the closest alternative and reverted to gcc.  Amazing what another set of eyes can do.  I'll upvote your answer though, it's good to know I was using an out of date method.

Answer (score 0):

Add option in yours command line for g++ [-std=c++11]