# Set GCC version for make in shell

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++

I have two gcc (same applies to g++) versions installed. The newer one is the default one:

```
/usr/bin/gcc      # 4.9.2
/usr/bin/gcc-4.4  # 4.4.7
```

For my make command I want to use gcc-4.4 / g++-4.4.

I've tried these three variantes but none seems to work:

```
export CC="gcc-4.4"
export CPP="g++-4.4"

export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.4
export CPP=/usr/bin/g++-4.4

export gcc=/usr/bin/gcc-4.4
export g++=/usr/bin/g++-4.4
```

The Makefile defines:

```
# Compiler Options
CC       = gcc
CPP      = g++
LD       = g++
```

The compiler used by the Makefile is still 4.9.2. How can I use 4.4.7?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[GNU Make manual, 6.10 Variables from the Environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Environment):

> Variables in `make` can come from the environment in which `make` is run. Every environment variable that make sees when it starts up is transformed into a make variable with the same name and value. However, **an explicit assignment in the makefile, or with a command argument, overrides the environment. (If the `-e` flag is specified, then values from the environment override assignments in the makefile. But this is not recommended practice.)**

The recommended practice is to pass these variables on `make` command line:

```
$ make CC=gcc-4.4 CPP=g++-4.4 CXX=g++-4.4 LD=g++-4.4
```

---

A side note is that `CXX` is used for compiling C++ code, whereas `CPP` is for preprocessing. Either the author of the makefile confused `CPP` with `CXX`, or the makefile indeed uses `CPP` for generating dependencies, which has been unnecessary for the last decade or so. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32379965/412080) for more details.